# NPE when sqlContext.createDateFrame()

Tags: java, apache-spark

I have the following code that I want to use to update a list of records into mysql db using spark.

```
DataFrame df = sqlContext.createDataFrame(airlineList, Airline.class);
sparkHelper.saveAirlinesToMysql(df);
```

The Airline.class is

```
@Getter @Setter
public class Airline implements Serializable {
    private Long id;
    private String name;
    private String referenceId;
    @Getter(AccessLevel.NONE)
    @Setter(AccessLevel.NONE)
    private Object[] parsedReferenceId;

    public Object[] getParsedReferenceId() {
        if (parsedReferenceId == null) {
            parsedReferenceId = ReferenceHelper.parseReferenceId(this.referenceId);
        }
        return parsedReferenceId;
    }
}
```

When I run the spark job to save to db, it shows me

```
ERROR [2019-07-17 05:06:49,505] com.api.command.SparkDriverCommand: Spark run failed due to NullPointerException at org.spark-project.guava.reflect.TypeToken.method(TypeToken.java:465)
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.spark-project.guava.reflect.TypeToken.method(TypeToken.java:465)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.JavaTypeInference$$anonfun$2.apply(JavaTypeInference.scala:110)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.JavaTypeInference$$anonfun$2.apply(JavaTypeInference.scala:109)
        at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:244)
        at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:244)
        at scala.collection.IndexedSeqOptimized$class.foreach(IndexedSeqOptimized.scala:33)
        at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayOps$ofRef.foreach(ArrayOps.scala:108)
        at scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.map(TraversableLike.scala:244)
        at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayOps$ofRef.map(ArrayOps.scala:108)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.JavaTypeInference$.org$apache$spark$sql$catalyst$JavaTypeInference$$inferDataType(JavaTypeInference.scala:109)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.JavaTypeInference$$anonfun$2.apply(JavaTypeInference.scala:111)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.JavaTypeInference$$anonfun$2.apply(JavaTypeInference.scala:109)
        at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:244)
        at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:244)
        at scala.collection.IndexedSeqOptimized$class.foreach(IndexedSeqOptimized.scala:33)
        at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayOps$ofRef.foreach(ArrayOps.scala:108)
        at scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.map(TraversableLike.scala:244)
        at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayOps$ofRef.map(ArrayOps.scala:108)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.JavaTypeInference$.org$apache$spark$sql$catalyst$JavaTypeInference$$inferDataType(JavaTypeInference.scala:109)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.JavaTypeInference$$anonfun$2.apply(JavaTypeInference.scala:111)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.JavaTypeInference$$anonfun$2.apply(JavaTypeInference.scala:109)
        at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:244)
        at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:244)
        at scala.collection.IndexedSeqOptimized$class.foreach(IndexedSeqOptimized.scala:33)
        at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayOps$ofRef.foreach(ArrayOps.scala:108)
        at scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.map(TraversableLike.scala:244)
        at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayOps$ofRef.map(ArrayOps.scala:108)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.JavaTypeInference$.org$apache$spark$sql$catalyst$JavaTypeInference$$inferDataType(JavaTypeInference.scala:109)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.JavaTypeInference$$anonfun$2.apply(JavaTypeInference.scala:111)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.JavaTypeInference$$anonfun$2.apply(JavaTypeInference.scala:109)
        at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:244)
        at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:244)
        at scala.collection.IndexedSeqOptimized$class.foreach(IndexedSeqOptimized.scala:33)
        at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayOps$ofRef.foreach(ArrayOps.scala:108)
        at scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.map(TraversableLike.scala:244)
        at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayOps$ofRef.map(ArrayOps.scala:108)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.JavaTypeInference$.org$apache$spark$sql$catalyst$JavaTypeInference$$inferDataType(JavaTypeInference.scala:109)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.JavaTypeInference$.inferDataType(JavaTypeInference.scala:54)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext.getSchema(SQLContext.scala:941)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext.createDataFrame(SQLContext.scala:603)
        at com.api.command.SparkDriverCommand.saveAirlines(SparkDriverCommand.java:485)
        at com.api.command.SparkDriverCommand.run(SparkDriverCommand.java:465)
        at com.api.command.SparkDriverCommand.run(SparkDriverCommand.java:107)
        at io.dropwizard.cli.ConfiguredCommand.run(ConfiguredCommand.java:85)
        at com.api.command.SparkDriverCommand.run(SparkDriverCommand.java:120)
```

I am wondering if it is because of the field parsedReferenceId has no setter and getter? Please help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Maybe some fields are `null` in the members of `List<Airline>` ? Check [this](http://queirozf.com/entries/debugging-nullpointerexception-in-apache-spark). Also the class you shared as `Airline` has a much different name; `SuggestionDismissalFollowup `